# Django mod-wsgi error 500 - nothing useful in log files

Tags: django, error-handling, mod-wsgi, error-log

I'm running my djnago application usind mod_wsg (I can't use built-in django server with some reasons)

When error occures and I see error 500, I'm looking for information in /var/log/apache2/errors.log , but there's no any useful information here.

If I have error with syntax or with database or in views - whatever! I'm getting error message about "UnicodeDecodeError". It looks like this:

```
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=10006): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/hosting/mysite/public/django.wsgi'.
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 221, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 66, in technical_500_response
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 275, in get_traceback_html
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     c = Context(self.get_traceback_data())
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 233, in get_traceback_data
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     frames = self.get_traceback_frames()
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 387, in get_traceback_frames
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     'vars': self.filter.get_traceback_frame_variables(self.request, tb.tb_frame),
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 183, in get_traceback_frame_variables
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     value = self.get_request_repr(value)
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 102, in get_request_repr
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return build_request_repr(request, POST_override=self.get_post_parameters(request))
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 179, in build_request_repr
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     unicode(meta)))
[Mon Apr 30 00:21:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 1556: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think that django tries to handle error exception and gets new error while this process. Something about encodings. But I don't know how to fix it.

How can I get information about my first error, not UnicodeDecodeError?
How can I fix UnicodeDecodeError? (After fixing it I hope to see my first error description in logs).

Comment: can you post your django.wsgi file?

Comment: Here it is:  
 
    import os  
    import sys  
 
    path = '/hosting/mysite'  
    if path not in sys.path:  
       sys.path.insert(0, path)  
 
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'  
    
    import django.core.handlers.wsgi  
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the Django documentation where it talks about this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#if-you-get-a-unicodeencodeerror

Also try setting DEBUG to True in Django settings module. It may allow the underlying error to be shown in browser. If this is a public facing site and you can't do that, then set ADMINS settings to email address as covered in Django documentation so details of errors are sent to you by email.

Comment: I added to `/etc/apache2/envvars` this two rows: `export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'` it doesn't helped  (tried 'ru_RU.UTF-8' - my native locale)  - nothing changed.

Comment: Not all Linux distros actually use /etc/apache2/envvars. Did you validate somehow from within the application that LANG and LC_ALL variables were then actually being set?

Comment: How can I test it? (Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: The envvars file is a shell script. Add a line: 'echo > /tmp/envvars.txt'. and if that file is created, then it was used.